# create label on fly and display error message

Tags: jquery

how to create label on fly and assign some error message to that label using jquery. I want display this message on the top. How to achieve this using jquery?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

```
$('<span></span>')
    .text('error message goes here')
    .appendTo('parent selector goes here');
```

Answer (score 0):

Well if you want it on the fly like jQuery validate does the initially start it on blur() like so:

```
$('.required').on('blur', function () {
   $(this).after('<span class="error">Required!</span>');
});​
```

Other logic, as to what the answer should be, you have to add to it, but the basics are there.

[jsFiddle link](http://jsfiddle.net/SqEaW/)